# How do I count turtle above, below, and diagonal using netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I am working on creating a connect four game using netlogo for an assignment.  I am having trouble keeping track of how many reds or blues are in a row. (determining the winner)

This is pretty much what I want it to do:

if this circle is red
         then add one to successive circles
      else
         set successive reds back down to 0
      if successive reds is 4 (or greater)
         show  you win buddy/gal
      else set successive-reds 0

This is what I have tried and does not work.

```
ifelse any? patches with [ (pcolor = red) and (pxcor 1)]
    [set successive-reds = successive-reds + 1]
    [set successive-reds 0]
    if successive-reds = 4
       [show "you won"]
```

I have searched stackoverflow for help and found ways to do this but not using the netlogo program.
I have also tried using neighbors and turtles-on and can not find a way to ask turtles to ask their neighboring turtle if their color is the same as the turtle asking.

any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Argh... I know that, since this is for an assignment, I should just gently guide you into figuring out for yourself how to do that, but this is such a cool little problem, for which NetLogo is so well suited, that I can't resist posting a solution:

```
to-report wins? ; patch procedure
  report member? true map wins-in-direction? n-values 8 [ ? * 45 ]
end

to-report wins-in-direction? [ h ] ; patch procedure
  report not member? false map [
    ([ pcolor ] of patch-at-heading-and-distance h ?) = red
  ] (n-values 4 [ ? ])
end
```

Given the above code, a statement like:

```
any? patches with [wins?]
```

...will tell you if any patch is the extremity of a winning sequence.

Now you should not use that code unless you understand it. The use of [`map`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map) and [`n-values`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#n-values) probably makes it a little challenging if you are not used to that style, but feel free to ask questions in the comments, and I'll update my answer to address them.

**Bonus points:** This only checks for a red win. Generalize this so it can check for another color, without naively duplicating the code.